# Google Script - add Gmail Attachment to document and Process in Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, email-attachments

So basically, My father asked me to create a script to find emails with a "Drive" label and save their contents to his drive.
(If your asking why, its so he can email himself a couple of PDF's and have the script automatically put them together in his drive)

And I've gotten the whole thing done except for one thing: Can't figure out how to save the attachments.
In the `processDocument` method I loop through the attachments and try to do:

```
doc.appendParagraph(the attachment)
```

Is there any proper way of adding the attachments using the `processDocument()` method?

Link to Code:
http://pastebin.com/RwFNs232

Thanks.

Comment: It's a good idea to post the code you are using in order to get better answers! Are you using Gmail service to read messages?

Comment: nanndoj, Yes i am using gmail service. Im doing it by searching all threads having attachments and the label drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DriveApp to save the attachment blob in a separated file:

```
var fileBlob = "your blob" // GmailAttachment.copyBlob() method;
var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
```

And then write in your doc the link to the attachment

```
doc.appendParagraph(file.getUrl());
```

**Note:**

You may want to write the attachment content in your document. In this case you can write directly to the doc without create a file in your Drive. But it is dangerous because you can't get some blob's content as a well formated string.

```
doc.appendParagraph("attachment content"); //GmailAttachment.getDataAsString()
```

I think it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, so basically i could create the file, put it in the document and then delete it? Giving it a try immediantly.

Comment: No. In this example you are writing a link to the file saved before in your Drive! I assume you are writing the email content in the doc and then the URL. If you want to write the content instead of the url you can try GmailAttachment.getDataAsString() method and see if it works

Comment: Oh, didnt even see the getUrl there! Going waay to fast. ill modify my code a bit to work with this. Thanks for the quickest answer i ever got!

Comment: nanndoj, One quick question: Is there a proper move function? I cant find any function that moves a certain file from somewhere to somewhere, im now just copying it over and removing the old ones.

Comment: That's a good question. I always use File.makeCopy(destination); But it changes the file ID. You can ask it as a separated question.

Answer (score 0):

As @nanndoj said, you should use the `blob` file structure to input the files. Additional information about blobs should be asked as a separate question.

However, the attachment should not just be appended to the `doc` of the email. Instead, you should include the blob reference in the call of the `sendEmail` function, as seen in [Google's documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)).

#### Example:

```
sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)

MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Two files are attached.', {
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
 });
```